# After upgrading could only login to terminal 22.04.3

Tags: graphics, login

I know very little about Ubuntu. I was given a popup window for several upgrades, was told I would have to reboot after the upgrade. During the installation of the upgrade the screen froze for over an hour. I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> and got a login to the terminal. How do I get the user friendly screen back?

`sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` didn't produce any error messages, it also didn't fix the problem. in fact the problem has gotten worse. On restarting before I can log in I get an error message about the display "**The system is running in low-graphics mode Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly you will need to configure these your self.**" Click ok and another popup with 4 options, I chose "**Try running with default graphic mode**" The other 3 options don't do anything to help.
I then get the terminal login type `startx` and get into the GUI. But it's now different, none of the activities have a minimize button and the aren't listed on the left side of the screen.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`. If it shows any error, take a screenshot with your phone, and post the error message by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1481090/edit) your question

Comment: Maybe related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1481093/ubuntu-22-04-2-lts-fails-after-an-update ?

Comment: Maybe also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/2030262

Answer (score 2):

Today, I had similar issue as you described and fixed it by:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

On my end, some of the drivers were also broken by the failed upgrade, so I fixed that issue with:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

Looks like the issue is caused by:
[Bug #2030262 System broken after upgrade](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/2030262)