# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS fails after an update

Tags: package-management, updates, 22.04, gui, update-manager

I enjoyed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, 64-bit desktop, kernel release 5.19.0-50-generic. It worked for a good long while, with zero issues on [Dell Vostro 3020 SFF](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/desktop-computers/new-vostro-small-form-factor/spd/vostro-3020-sff/usevspbts3020fyjn#tech-specs-anchor).

Today, the OS suggested that I have a conflict in my packages (a red stop sign icon on the top-right menu bar). The message that appeared is:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.
> The error message was: 'Error: Marking the upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)' This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies

When I clicked Show updates, a window saying: "Sorry, Ubuntu 22.04 has experienced an internal error." appears with the following details:

```
ExecutablePath : /usr/bin.update-notifier
Package : update-notifier 3.192.54.5
ProblemType : Crash
Title : update-notifier crachsed with SIGSEGV in g_hash_table_lookup()
ApportVersion : 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.3
Architecture : amd64
...
```

So I updated using Terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

After the update, the computer only boots into text mode.

I reinstalled Ubuntu. I got the graphical interface, but the stop sign icon, with the message appeared within minutes. I presume because there is some update to the OS out there, that all new installations fetch. In other words, I am probably no longer getting the stable OS that I used to have.

In summary: If I don't update, the error persists, and if I update, the OS fails to boot properly.

What do I do?

Comment: Is gdm3 installed? I wonder if you're running into this issue: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2489595

Comment: cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager shows: `/usr/sbin/gdm3` and 
systemctl status display-manager.service shows: `gdm3.service`, `loaded /etc/init.d/gdm3`, and `active (exited)`

Comment: I think that that above means gdm3 was running. Interestingly, however, when I run, `sudo apt install gdm3` it installed a lot of staff and entered the GUI. Thanks @AdamMonsen. It does seem that this is a widespread problem. What I need is a stable release. Does anyone think that 20.04 LTS will be better in that regard?

Comment: I'm guessing not. Both are LTS releases, but 22.04 is newer--I'd stick with that. See https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle . Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1481090/after-upgrading-could-only-login-to-terminal-22-04-3 ... that might be the same issue you're seeing.

Comment: Looks like the issue is caused by https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/2030262