# When installing update in Ubuntu the screen went black then the prompt kept flashing and when I restart the machine the terminal is displayed

Tags: updates

Here in my environment the same thing happened when trying to install the Ubuntu updates, the screen just went black then the prompt kept flashing and when I restart the machine the terminal is displayed but the graphical environment is not displayed, searching on the Net I see that it is a problem that affected many people around the world, as the cause was generated by an update released by canonical, I believe that only they can solve it

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1481199/1157209